# Does actually WinRT support WPF o Silverlight Development?

Tags: windows-runtime

Does actually WinRT support WPF o Silverlight Development?

Which languages are used to work with WinRT application interfaces?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it doesn't support these. It works with C++, C#, VB.NET and JavaScript officially.